Identify Tale: King kills Wife Out of Distrust, Goes Blind, then Regains Sight
I read a this tale long time ago and need help identifying the King.
It goes like this: one day a King kills his wife out of jealousy and distrust. He loses his sight due to this event. He goes on a penance and realises his mistakes after guidance from a sage or god. He regains his sight after asking for forgiveness. He then renounces his kingdom and makes it his mission to remove distrust among people.

Language: English
Origin: India
Period: Prehistoric India (Vedic Period)
Last Read: Around 5-10 years back
Source: Book about Kings & Legends (Don't remember exactly)

Who was the king?
